# Формирование csv файла (текст на польском языке) для Excel в кодировке UTF-8

Tags: c#, кодировка, excel

Пишу парсер для польского сайта. Результат парсинга заносится в csv файл, который потом открывается в Excel. Текст на польском языке. Использую следующую команду для записи текста в файл:

```
File.AppendAllText(tmpFile,Result + Environment.NewLine,Encoding.UTF8);
```

На моем компьютере запись происходит нормально (например, название категории `Produkty IKEA FAMILY|Bezpieczeństwo`). Однако на другом компьютере результат такой - `Produkty IKEA FAMILY|BezpieczeЕ„stwo`. Из-за подобных метаморфоз в тексте появляются лишние знаки `"` кавычек, что рушит всю структуру csv файла.

Почему это работает на одном компьютере, но не работает на другом? Или хотя бы как экранировать кавычки до записи в файл, ведь тут, как я понимаю, кавычки появляются после перекодировки, то есть внутри функции `File.AppendAllText`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, проблема в кодировке строки Result. Откуда она берется и каким способом? Если строка Result не в UTF8, то при записи в файл будет добавлен результат преобразования этой строки в UTF8, а с этим есть некоторые заморочки, так как конвертируется не байтовое представление строки, а символьное. Поскольку разным символам в разных кодировках соответствуют разные коды, то байтовое представление строки до и после преобразования может отличаться. Попробуйте сделать что-то похожее на это (кодировка windows-1250 приведена для примера):

```
Encoding srcEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1250); //windows-1250 Central European (Windows)
byte[] codes = srcEncoding.GetBytes(Result);
string utf8Result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(codes);
File.AppendAllText(tmpFile, utf8Result + Environment.NewLine, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: @Valeriy Karchov строка берется с сайта, парсится. Как узнать, в какой кодировке представлен текст на сайте? В html есть такой тег:

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

Похоже, текст на сайте тоже utf8. Значит, в теории все должно работать нормально?